# sslstrip ImportError: No module named twisted.web

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

I can't get sslstrip to work... When I run `sslstrip` I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sslstrip", line 27, in <module>
    from twisted.web import http
ImportError: No module named twisted.web
```

Heres some information that could be useful:

-I'm using Kubuntu 20.04. I'm running all commands as superuser. I already ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` successfully.

-I also ran `apt-get install python-twisted-web` and `pip3 install twisted` successfully.

-Trying `pip install twisted` instead shows this (didn't manage to fix this either):

```
Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.
```

-Running `ls -al /usr/bin/python` shows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 abr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

-Running `which sslstrip | head -1` shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/sslstrip
```

I can't think of any possible additional info but If you need to know anything let me know.
I've seen so many posts about this same problem on many different forums but none seems to have been solved and no solutions provided have worked for me or the ops so I hope it goes different this time.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having some difficulty installing sslstrip too.
This is what worked for me.
I started with a fresh copy of kali then ran pimpmykali from "https://github.com/Dewalt-arch/pimpmykali"

After this installed a couple of python modules where next on the list.
twisted and service_identity.
'pip install twisted'
With service_identity I first downloaded the whl from https://pypi.org/project/service_identity/#files
'pip install service_identity-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl '

then 'python sslstrip' works like a charm.